# CartoDB Torque by type?

Tags: carto, torque

I have a pretty robust dataset of .gpx files i'm animating with the torque layer style. I'd like to be able to color the map by type using a column...for me its 'car' vs 'flight' vs 'train. This works with simple colors, but havent had luck with the torque and css.

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour].  Also, please do not post in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Torque map using different categories, you could try Torque Cat in the CartoDB Editor's Wizards. 
Selecting the column by which you want to categorize your data on 'Category Column' in the Torque Cat wizard would do the trick.

Check [this example](https://team.cartodb.com/u/ernestomb/viz/934cea08-7d5f-11e5-8476-0e31c9be1b51/public_map) to see if that's what you are looking for.